# Show correct thumnail image in the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-gallery, magnific-popup

I am working on magnific-popup gallery and trying to achieve gallery design as show in image below [image]

So far i managed to make it look like as it is show in image. But it always show image from the first image irrespective of which mage we click in the image gallery.

here is the codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvFxH

I am not sure how to fix it so that it can start the sequence from image user click on and also hide left or right arrow it is first or last image in the galler

CODE

```
<div id="gallery1" class="mfp-hide">

  <div class="slide">
    <div class="imgg"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg/800px-Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg"  />  </div>
    <div class="detailss">
      <span class="d-title">This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
      <span class="d-hr">Download</span>
      <span class="d-date">01-01-2014</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="imgg"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Water_Dolphin.jpg/800px-Water_Dolphin.jpg"  />  </div>
  <div class="detailss">
      <span class="d-title">This is image two</span>
      <span class="d-hr">Download</span>
      <span class="d-date">02-02-2014</span>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="imgg"><img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower1.jpg"  />  </div>
  <div class="detailss">
      <span class="d-title">This is image three</span>
      <span class="d-hr">Download</span>
      <span class="d-date">03-03-2014</span>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>


<a href="#gallery1" class="open-gallery-link">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg/800px-Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg" width="172" height="115" />  
</a>

<a href="#gallery1" class="open-gallery-link">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Water_Dolphin.jpg/800px-Water_Dolphin.jpg" width="172" height="115" />  
</a>
<a href="#gallery1" class="open-gallery-link">
  <img src="http://i1232.photobucket.com/albums/ff372/Marcin_Gil/magnific%20example/flower1.jpg" width="172" height="115" />  
</a>
```

Comment: That's the right behaviour. You should read the docs/contact the dev and ask how you can choose the default item shown. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some incorrect code... this is my code:

---

### [Live Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/fp4uq2w1/)

---

### [Demo 2 - Next/Prev Button](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/fp4uq2w1/15/)

---

**HTML**

```
<div id='gallery'>
    <div class='imgwrapper'>
        <img src='http://8pic.ir/images/6s75jpffwom32fhct7q4.jpg' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'>15-02-2013</span>
        <span class='info'>This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
        <a href='http://gah-blog.blogspot.com/'>download</a>
    </div>
    <div class='imgwrapper'>
        <img src='http://8pic.ir/images/ypzla17xaqmhjiocih64.jpg' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'>10-07-2013</span>
        <span class='info'>This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
        <a href='http://gah-blog.blogspot.com/'>download</a>
    </div>
    <div class='imgwrapper'>
        <img src='http://8pic.ir/images/tuwvju35ajgts0rxzufw.jpg' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'>21-10-2013</span>
        <span class='info'>This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
        <a href='http://gah-blog.blogspot.com/'>download</a>
    </div>
    <div class='imgwrapper'>
        <img src='http://8pic.ir/images/usra1shyel8nxudsj8vs.jpg' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'>02-02-2014</span>
        <span class='info'>This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
        <a href='http://gah-blog.blogspot.com/'>download</a>
    </div>
    <div class='imgwrapper'>
        <img src='http://8pic.ir/images/vp7wnu7ohpx2i3im6nem.jpg' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'>20-05-2014</span>
        <span class='info'>This is the caption of the image along with some other information</span>
        <a href='http://gah-blog.blogspot.com/'>download</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="popupbg">
    <div id="popup">
        <img src='' title='' alt=''/>
        <span class='date'></span>
        <span class='info'></span>
        <a href=''>download</a>
        <span class="btn" id="close">Close</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#gallery{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background:#e7e7e7;
}
.imgwrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.imgwrapper img{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.imgwrapper span,.imgwrapper a{
    display:none;
}
#popupbg{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.92);
    z-index:1000;
}
#popup{
    position:relative;
    top:5%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:17px;
    width:70%;
    height:65%;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    border:solid 10px #CCCCCC;
}
#popup img{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:95%;
    height:200px;
}
#popup span.date,#popup span.info,#popup span#close{
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".imgwrapper").click(function(){
        var img=$(' > img', this).attr("src");
        var date=$(' > span.date', this).html();
        var info=$(' > span.info', this).html();
        var a=$(' > a', this).attr("href");

        $('#popup img').attr("src",img);
        $('#popup span.date').html(date);
        $('#popup span.info').html(info);
        $('#popup a').attr("href",a);

        user_guide()
    });
});

function user_guide(){
    $("#popupbg").fadeToggle("slow");
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#popupbg").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you can change UI

Comment: Thanks i can change the UI to my required design but can we add next & previous buttons to this...

Comment: I have updated your code, `http://jsfiddle.net/fp4uq2w1/4/` i have two question regarding same can we add Next, Pre button to it and can we center align the copy in center of the page.

Comment: Thanks you, I have slightly modified your code to add thumbnail images... example `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGblH?editors=100`. I also noticed that you use `id='a', id='b'` which will limit the number of images to 26 only. I tried replacing id with numeric value 1,2.. but that breaks the script as it is not recommended also. I will try to find a way by which we can add more image by working on name id as `id='a_1', id='a_2'`. anyways thank you very much...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you're welcome ... this is what you want ... `http://codepen.io/mostafaznv/pen/EvjAK`

Comment: thank you... exactly... I will now work on css to make it pretty.

Comment: Oh! you are using ` if(status==0) status=6;` you also specify the last number of image isn't. i think i can manage it i will pass this number from code-behind(c#) to java-script variable so that script is dynamic in nature as i have to generate image gallery from database..

Comment: May be i am confused with `if(status==0) status=6; ` what exactly is `status=6;` number 6 here is it the total number of image. i changes it to 3 and script still worked so this has just added to my confusion.

Comment: `if(status==0)` means, user clicked back button in first image `(id=1)` in popup ... when user clicked on back button (on first image), script should show last image `(status==6)` ... @KnowledgeSeeker

Comment: if(status==0) status=`last image id`;

Comment: and, if(status==`last image id`+`1`) status==1;